# Getting list of tuples based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two relations

```
Author (authorId, authorName, country)

PrizeWinner (mAuthId, fAuthId, year)
```

where:

```
fk(mAuthId) -> authorId of Author 
fk(fAuthId) -> authorId of Author
```

PrizeWinner table contains the Id of male and female pair who has won the award for best authors for given year.

**We need to list out all the winning Authors pairs, when male (mAuthID) and female author (fAuthId) are from the same country**

Any help or clue on this will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT male.*, female.*
FROM 
    PrizeWinner p
        INNER JOIN Author male ON male.authorId = p.mAuthId
        INNER JOIN Author female ON female.authorId = p.fmAuthId
WHERE
    male.country = female.country
```

regarding to your comment, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT all.authorName, all.country
FROM 
    PrizeWinner p
        INNER JOIN Author male ON male.authorId = p.mAuthId
        INNER JOIN Author female ON female.authorId = p.fmAuthId
        INNER JOIN Author all ON all.authorId = male.authorId OR all.authorId = female.authorId
WHERE
    male.country = female.country
```

Comment: @DSJ, I'm not sure whether your suggestion matches. Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: Thank you,I think this will result me pair , I just want a list of authors and their country in output. (AuthorName1, US ), (Auth2,US) etc.